# SQL Server - Reset custom identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns `ID` and `SubDetail`. I have created custom identity like `2018XX` for the `ID` columns with `2018` as current year and `XX` as a number and it will start from "01". I have searched for some topic about "Reset identity field - SQL Server" but It only showed how to reset only number identity field. I'm confused that is there anyway to reset custom identity field.

Here is my SQL query code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spAddSubWareHouse
     (@SubDetail VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxDetailID INT 

    SELECT @maxDetailID = MAX(CAST(RIGHT(ID, 2) AS INT)) 
    FROM SubWareHouse

    IF (@maxDetailID IS NULL)
        SET @maxDetailID = 1 
    ELSE 
        SET @maxDetailID += 1

    --insert
    INSERT INTO SubWareHouse 
    VALUES (CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@maxDetailID AS VARCHAR), 2), @SubDetail) 
END
```

Comment: *custom identity like "2018XX"*  Isn't that a computed column ?

Comment: Post your code for the custom identity implementation.

Comment: @Pரதீப்Yes, XX is number from "01" to "99". We only have detail information about 50 rows

Comment: @DanGuzman I added my SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother doing this.  Simply have a numeric identity column defined as:

```
id int identity(1, 1) primary key
```

You can then store the `year` as a separate column, because that appears to be information that you want.

Why do it this way?  There are many reasons.  First, `identity` is built into the database.  So, identity columns are guaranteed to be unique even when multiple applications are doing inserts at the same time.

Second, integers are more efficient (slightly) for foreign key references.

Third, the locking required to do what you really want is very cumbersome and could significantly slow down your system.  Plus, any implementation to prevent duplicates could have a bug -- so why not use the built-in mechanisms?

If you need to get the sequence number for a given year, it is easy enough using `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by year order by id) as year_sequence_number
```

Comment: Thank for your advice. Because my table SubWareHouse is linked to table SubWareHouse in Oracle. I dont have any permission to modify table. I just can map data from my table to Oracle table.